# How to generate an empty method?

Tags: java, soap, xsd, jaxb

I have xsd file with elements, I generate java-classes from them. I have getters and setters for elements in these classes. Is it possible to add some text in the xsd-file, to just have an empty void method in generated classes?

```
<xs:complexType name="FutureCardHolders">      
        <xs:annotation><xs:documentation>Future Card Holders</xs:documentation></xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Holder" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:complexContent>
                        <xs:extension base="FutureCardHolder"/>
                    </xs:complexContent>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
```

At some moment I have a structure declared with this class, but actually filled with children. I want to be able to call this method with child's implementation.

Comment: can you please share your Xsd?

Comment: @JunedAhsan I could imagine (s)he wants to do this to fulfill the requirements of a certain interface